# Как в grid-контейнере запретить блокам растягиваться по высоте?

Tags: html, css, grid

Есть примерно такая разметка (смотреть лучше в развёрнутом виде на всю страницу):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 60vh;
  display: grid;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
h1 {
  margin: 20px 20px 0;
}
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 0 25px;
  align-self: start;
}
.nav li {
  padding: 5px 20px;
}
.scroll {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: auto;
}
.item {
  width: 24%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 1% 1% 0;
}
.home {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>ЗАГОЛОВОК</h1>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>Пункт меню 1</li>
    <li>Пункт меню 2</li>
    <li>Пункт меню 3</li>
    <li>Пункт меню 4</li>
    <li>Пункт меню 5</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="scroll">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="home">На главную</a>
</div>
```

Чтобы у блока `.scroll` появлялась полоса прокрутки при переполнении без указания явной высоты, я задаю контейнеру свойство `display: grid`. Когда айтемов внутри `.scroll` много, всё работает хорошо. Но добавляются они туда динамически, и их количество может быть недостаточным для скролла. Тогда остальные элементы в контейнере (прежде всего меню и ссылка "на главную") начинают заполнять собой освободившееся пространство, т.е. растягиваются по высоте:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 60vh;
  display: grid;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
h1 {
  margin: 20px 20px 0;
}
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 0 25px;
  align-self: start;
}
.nav li {
  padding: 5px 20px;
}
.scroll {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: auto;
}
.item {
  width: 24%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 1% 1% 0;
}
.home {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>ЗАГОЛОВОК</h1>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>Пункт меню 1</li>
    <li>Пункт меню 2</li>
    <li>Пункт меню 3</li>
    <li>Пункт меню 4</li>
    <li>Пункт меню 5</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="scroll">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <!--<div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>-->
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="home">На главную</a>
</div>
```

Каким образом можно запретить растягивание по высоте? align-items или align-self к результату не приводят.

Comment: добавь `grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr auto;` - чтобы `scroll` занимал все доступное свободное место

Comment: @Grundy, супер, спасибо огромное!